# iPhone 4 no longer detects SIM card, how can I fix it?

Tags: iphone, sim

Since 3 months I do have an iPhone 4, 3 weeks ago i started to get **no SIM card installed** error increasingly more frequent. Right now the phone is unusable. I went to a sales office of my mobile supplier, they tried a different sim card. But this did not solve the issue unfortunately.

They want it now for reparation, which means i loose my iphone for 2 or 3 weeks. Are there any other possibilities, on the internet I read a few sites which speak about sticky tape or applying some glue to the simcard slider. But I don't want to run the risk of losing my warranty and ruining the iphone's interior.

I have the feeling that the problem is only at the slider, so I'm a kind of dissatisfied with the iphone being taken in 2 weeks for service.
Are there any other options?

Answer (score 4):

Take it to the Apple store if there is one near you. Usually they will switch out the phone if still under warranty.

Comment: And they will switch out the phone within 15 minutes or so.  You are much better off dealing with Apple than a carrier if that's physically possible.

Comment: New phone is much better than sticking with an old repaired one ;)

Answer (score 1):

Where do you live?

Most Apple stores will exchange the device while you wait. Mail in service is similarly one day upon receipt - so anyone quoting 2 weeks is either being really cautious and not using express shipping or expects to send it to a shop that will try to repair the insides rather than swapping it as Apple does.

I would contact Apple directly at http://www.apple.com/support/country/index.html?dest=applecare and ask for a quote before waiting 2-3 weeks.